# Is there any way to simplify this PHP code?

Tags: php

```
$a = $_POST['year'];
$b = $_POST['mileage'];
$c = is_numeric($a);
$d = is_numeric($b);
if ($c == False && $d == False) {
    echo = "$c & $d variables are not numeric";
} else {
    echo = "$c & $d variables are numeric";
}
```

This is a code that I whipped while learning PHP. Is there anyone that can help me simplify them. I don't like how it looked. I feel that it is too long. Beginner here (",)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes breaking down the way you set values can be useful, especially with complex calculations as it helps to debug the code.

But with simple assignments it is better (IMHO) to try and reduce the number of extra steps you make in your code.  Setting a variable to then use it in another step is an overhead for both the computer (although negligible) but also adds extra lines of code.  So assuming you just want to show if they are both numeric or not you can roll up all of those variables into the `if` statement...

```
if (is_numeric($_POST['year']) == False && is_numeric($_POST['mileage']) == False) {
    echo "variables are not numeric";
} else {
    echo "variables are numeric";
}
```

This does assume you have already checked that `$_POST['year']` and `$_POST['mileage']` are set (as does your code), you can use `$_POST['mileage'] ?? ''` if you want to make it more flexible.

Also the code only says the variables are not numeric if both values are not numeric.  Change the `&&` to `||` for either values not being numeric.